# NVDA isn't reading multiple aria-live tags on single web page.

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, wai-aria

I am using multiple aria-live tags on a webpage, and when an error is shown on webpage NVDA only reads the first error message and not all.
I have user aria-live="assertive" also have also tried with aria-live="polite" but not working, can anyone provide some solution for it.
below is my code:

```
<div>
        <input type="text" name="username" tabIndex="0"/>
        <span class="usernameerr" role="alert" aria-live="assertive">Enter User Name</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="passowrd" name="password" tabIndex="0"/>
        <span class="passworderr" role="alert" aria-live="assertive">Enter Password</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="repassword" tabIndex="0"/>
        <span class="repassworderr" role="alert" aria-live="assertive">Renter Password</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" tabIndex="0"/>
    </div>
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: a helpful link: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/72271/screenreader-multiple-live-regions

Answer (score 1):

If you have `role=alert`, that implies `aria-live=assertive`.  When you have `aria-live=assertive`, a screen reader **might** clear the queue of pending messages.  So if you have three assertive areas, they might step on each other and clear the other messages.  The last one probably wins.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-live.  It says "User agents or assistive technologies MAY choose to clear queued changes when an assertive change occurs."

So you might hear the problem with one screen reader and not another.  You can test it out by removing `role=alert` **and** changing `aria-live` to `polite`.  (You said you tried it with `aria-live=polite` but if you didn't remove the `alert` role, then it still would have been `assertive`.)

Comment: tried removing role="alert" and adding aria-live="polite" but not reading any of tag.
only when there is role="alert" then only NVDA reads the first occurrence. also with only aria-live="assertive" also it does not reads.

Comment: The same issue persist with me, tried with aria-live="polite" and run with NVDA in chrome browser, it does not work. Can anyone help me with the solution.

Comment: In the past, chrome has not fully supported `aria-live` so it could be a browser bug.  When I've tested on chrome in the past, one version it would work and the next version it wouldn't.  It wasn't consistent.  Chrome is generally not a high priority platform for screen readers.  Many companies test for JAWS with Internet Explorer, NVDA with Firefox, and Voiceover on iOS (and Mac).  You can certainly test JAWS and NVDA on chrome, but if something doesn't work, make sure you test on other browser/AT combinations because your code might be correct and chrome might be wrong.